# How to add Login/Register link in the right header in Skeleton theme

Tags: theming

I am using [Skeleton](https://drupal.org/project/skeletontheme) theme with Drupal 7 in my website. Below is a screenshot of it-

[image]

As you can see, the right header is completely empty here. I want to add "Login | Register" links in this block in the following manner-

[image: This is Danland theme]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drupal has this feature where you can create menu links for user/login and user/logout and only the appropriate one will be displayed automatically. Same goes for user/register.

So create a new menu, add links "Login" (user/login), "Logout" (user/logout) and "Register" (user/register). In admin/structure/block move your new menu to where you need, and apply necessary styling.

Comment: It works.. thanks but after placing it in "Header Right" region, the website half logo is displaying in the next row (https://db.tt/eAV8J4Vi), which is annoying. Please help me to add the necessary style. (Note that, I don't wanna place this menu in "Header Top Right" region.)

Comment: @RaviJoshi yes, you will have to apply the Grid based css classes appropriately, or use some custom CSS rules to position your new block as desired. This is *your* theme now, changing from SkeletonTheme -- as it does not support this out the box, i suggest researching more on the theme's CSS and general CSS usage.

Answer (score 1):

Once you create the login menu as described Kari, It will be available as a block. Then you have to place the block in Header top right region.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to increase the width of the Logo and site slogan region (Header left - may be). Make sure to apply the grid classes properly.